# How do we promote this site?

Tags: discussion

Besides being "one of the 7 meta-questions every site should ask", it's just plain important. An "AI Stackexchange" site has been tried before, at least once, and possibly a few times. And in the past, it's been killed for lack of activity.

So, how do we promote this site well enough to attract a critical mass of participants? And how do we get people to participate?

Comment: I guess the first step is to clearly define its scope.

Comment: [A Recipe to Promote your Site](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/)

Comment: Related: http://meta.ai.stackexchange.com/questions/22/can-we-send-messages-to-young-researchers-who-have-recently-published-papers-in

Answer (score 5):

As Franck neatly put: First step would be to clearly define the scope of the site.

Next, there are very active Data Science, AI and ML communities on Reddit and other community sites like facebook groups, etc; and they would be an excellent way to get new users.

And as AI is a very hot topic right now, we would be getting traffic and users as long as we keep the scope well pruned and the posts well curated.

Comment: AI is hot right now, but there are also lots of places one can have conversations (like Reddit, for example).  So we need to figure out how to get people here specifically, if we want a community on this site in particular.

One idea I had was finding a way to reach out to students taking the various MOOC's on AI and AI related topics.  Yes, it might mean getting some "homework questions" but we could possibly attract some really enthusiastic participants.  But how to reach them in particular?

Comment: Awesome. I am currently doing Udacity's ML nano-degree.  Would make it a point to post in the course forum :)

Comment: Is there any discussion for a scope definition already?

Answer (score 3):

Once we figure out what we're about exactly, we need to haul in some real experts.

This is a good idea right here: [Can we send messages to young researchers who have recently published papers in artificial intelligence related journals during the private beta?](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22/75) Scholarly papers generally include their authors' e-mail addresses. Papers that don't have e-mails will at least have author names, and some Googling could turn up contact information.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one idea:  Search Meetup.com for meetups which are related to artificial intelligence, and post this link to their message boards and / or mailing lists, with a brief note saying "you may find this of interest".

Answer (score 0):

I think that we could try to promote the site with people from a broad range of disciplines. I remember seeing on Area51 what other people committed to, and there were mostly engineering or computer-related sites. Perhaps we need some philosophers, some psychologists, some neuroscientists and linguists here.

Maybe encouraging questions on other sites of the SX-network?

Or social networks posts?

---

I also wanted to add another site which has overlapping topics: [Cognitive Sciences](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I think Stack Exchange A.I. site is self-promoted and it does not need promotion. We just need a bit more time, that's all. I think this site has enough active experts so far, so our *answer ratio* is fine (1.8 at the time of writing).

Secondly given Stack Exchange higher ranked [SEO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization) abilities, people looking for A.I. answers will quickly find this place. Especially having in mind that A.I. is more likely to be the next big boom for this century, I believe next year we'll hit the [site healthy stats](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1225/8) without even promoting it.

Although if we decide to promote it, we need to be careful, as promoting this site to the wrong communities, this can result in lot of people asking the broad and opinion based posts.

Artificial promotion isn't a good one, but sharing the AI links to the good answers on relevant forum posts or reddit-like sites is a great start.