# Can we send messages to young researchers who have recently published papers in artificial intelligence related journals during the private beta?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

During the private beta we have the opportunity to send Emails via stack exchange:
[image]
And because stackexchange is already well-known on the net, it is more probable that our invitation will be read and clicked on. And I don't think there would be any academic mail server which rejects mail sent by the domain stackexchange.com.
As you know [there are a lot of artificial intelligence related journals](http://www.scimagojr.com/journalrank.php?category=1702), I want to see if it is useful or allowed to use the emails of some of those young researchers who have published papers in this journals recently and introduce them this new site?
Because my friends or the people that I have met directly will always notice the emails sent by me personally but a stranger may consider it a spam.

Comment: Related: [What kind of experts are we trying to attract?](http://meta.ai.stackexchange.com/q/40/8)

Comment: Was this strategy helpful? Did you attract any young researcher to the site through this? If yes, what was the text of the email that you sent to them?

Comment: Has anybody tried doing this yet?

Answer (score 12):

Certainly, asking real AI researchers to join would be great!

Paper authors include their e-mail addresses in their publications exactly for the purpose of being contacted about their work. I'm sure it would bring most students great happiness to know that their work has been noticed.

Students who aren't terribly busy will probably be willing to read all the e-mails they receive in their academic/professional e-mail inboxes, no matter whether the messages from from an `@stackexchange.com` address or a personal address. Indeed, composing a personal (non-automated) message mentioning how you enjoyed a paper would be appreciated, even if the person doesn't have the time or inclination to check out our site.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that sounds like an excellent idea to me.

Answer (score 4):

Technically I guess you could, but I think it would be fair to add some warnings such as the site might closed, and questions on Stack Exchange are sometimes deleted or closed for moderation reason.